# Can I use my NNID on another Wii U?

Tags: wii-u, nintendo-network-id

Splatoon is coming out soon, I'll have it, but immediately after picking it up I need to catch a plane to my parents' house. They also have a Wii U.

Can I use my NNID on her Wii U, have my online progress saved, and not affect anything about my account being the primary user of my Wii U at home?

I know other systems allow this, but you can never tell with Nintendo.

Comment: I don't know about the WiiU, but for their other systems, their digital stuff is tracked by console and not the online account.  This includes on the 3DS, which also uses NNIDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Nintendo Support pages](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2210/~/can-i-log-into-my-nintendo-network-id-on-a-different-system%3F), this isn't possible. Each Nintendo Network ID must be linked to at most one 3DS and one Wii U at the same time.

Your case is somewhat different, since you will only play one Wii U at a time, but you won't be able to login on your second Wii U, and you will be unable to download Splatoon on your second Wii U.

Nintendo will change that in the future, but [it will be reserved to future platforms](http://www.nintendo.co.jp/ir/en/library/events/140130/03.html).

---

You should not buy Splatoon via eShop if you are planning to play it on several consoles, and instead you should consider buying a physical copy of the game.

Since Nintendo games's saves are stored on consoles, and not linked to your copy of the game, both consoles will have an independent save and an independent online progress.